# Generate scala avro specific records using sbt-avrohugger

Tags: scala, sbt, avrohugger

I am trying generate Scala case classes implementing `SpecificRecord` using 
[sbt-avrohugger](https://github.com/julianpeeters/sbt-avrohugger). It works amazing when I have a clean slate and all I have is avro files in src/main/avro. But I am kinda stuck on generating scala classes for incremental changes for the avro. I am using

```
addSbtPlugin("com.julianpeeters" % "sbt-avrohugger" % "2.0.0-RC15")
```

And my build.sbt has :

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += (avroScalaGenerateSpecific in Compile).taskValue
avroSpecificScalaSource in Compile := new java.io.File("/Users/me/project/myschemas/scalacaseclasses")
```

1) Is there a way to generate scala case classes for the incremental changes of the avro without deleting existing scala classes(Have to do this or else when I compile , it is complaining that

> [error]
>   /Users/me/project/myschemas/scalacaseclasses/com/project/schemas/user/User.scala:6:
>   User is already defined as case class User
>   ). It doesn't complain when starting fresh with a clean slate.

Basically my situation is I have a bunch of avros:
Users, Visitors and some other classes. Say I had name and Id in User in 1st version , then i added address for User. I was wondering if this is possible to regenerate case classes for already existing classes .

Or the only way to achieve this is to just generate case classes for each new avro file.

PS: I already have a work around for this , where in I loop on each new avro file and copy new classes but I wanted to see if there was a better way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen with the following setup:

```
avroSpecificScalaSource in Compile := (Compile / baseDirectory).value / "myschemas/scalacaseclasses"
```